# PHP How to send multiple values within the same name

Tags: php, html, arrays, input

So here is my current code. This code has 6 inputs within the form. The names on the last 3 inputs are. firstanswer, secondanswer and thirdanswer.

```
<form action="addsurvey.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="surveyname">
  <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="First Question">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="firstanswer" value="">
  <input type="text" name="secondanswer" value="">
  <input type="text" name="thirdanswer" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

When they get submitted the php file I set the variables like this.

```
$firstanswer = $_POST['firstanswer'];
$secondanswer = $_POST['secondanswer'];
$thirdanswer = $_POST['thirdanswer'];

$answers = array();

array_push($answers, $firstanswer);
array_push($answers, $secondanswer);
array_push($answers, $thirdanswer);
```

This code would make sense if I knew every single user was going to only enter in three possible answers for their form. But I do not know for sure. Is there a way I can use the same name on the last three inputs and send them into some sort of array for example.

```
<form action="addsurvey.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="surveyname">
  <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="First Question">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="answer" value="">
  <input type="text" name="answer" value="">
  <input type="text" name="answer" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Then in the php it would be pushed onto an array.
To recap. I want to be able to use the same name for the inputs to then add into an array.

Comment: sure you can just use `name="answer[]"`, it'll get all of the inputs in array form, when the form is submitted just access it as you normally would `$answers = $_POST['answer'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send inputs as array `answer`. Then you will have these values in array variable `$_POST['answer']` with corresponding IDs or you can send without IDs and then type `name="answer[]"`.

```
<form action="addsurvey.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="surveyname">
  <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="First Question">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="answer[1]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="answer[2]" value="">
  <input type="text" name="answer[3]" value="">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an array name in html 'name'. You can use the array for the all input with the same name, so as i can understand you need below

```
    <form action="addsurvey.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="surveyname">
        <input type="text" name="question" placeholder="First Question">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" value="">
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" value="">
        <input type="text" name="answer[]" value="">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

it will solve the issue you have.